# How to define default schema for sequelize migrations when using postgres and umzug?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, umzug

I am trying to always run migrations with sequelize and umzug to a specific postgresql database schema. Lets call it `custom` schema. By default all queries go to `public` schema.
**Is there any way to define the default schema to run all migrations to in sequelize or umzug?**

- http://docs.sequelizejs.com/
- https://github.com/sequelize/umzug

## Background:

With the following code I am able to define the schema for a single query in a migration:

```
// schema defined according to https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/migrations/
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return Sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
      await queryInterface.renameTable({ tableName: 'oldtablename', schema: "custom"}, 'newtablename', { transaction })
    })
  },

  down: async () => {
  }
}
```

And it reports that it is a success and uses the correct schema:

```
Migration {
  path:
   'path/to/migrations/migration_test.js',
  file: 'migration_test.js',
  options:
   { storage: 'sequelize',
     storageOptions: [Object],
     logging: [Function: bound consoleCall],
     upName: 'up',
     downName: 'down',
     migrations: [Object],
     schema: 'custom' } } ]
```

However what I require is to be able to define the default schema that all queries in all migrations always run to instead of defining the schema I need in every single query I want to run.

I tried searching, reading the documentation of the libraries and copy pasting `schema: 'custom'` everywhere, but nothing else worked so far except the above example.

I am using the following code to run the migrations:

```
const sequelizeConn = new Sequelize(ENV_DB_URL, {
  schema: 'custom',
  logging: false
})

    const migrator = new Umzug({
      storage: 'sequelize',
      storageOptions: {
        sequelize: sequelizeConn,
        tableName: 'migrations',
        schema: 'custom'
      },
      logging: console.log,
      migrations: {
        params: [
          sequelizeConn.getQueryInterface(),
          sequelizeConn
        ],
        path: `${process.cwd()}/src/database/migrations`,
        pattern: /\.js$/
      }
    })
    migrator.up()
```

My umzug is `2.2.0` and sequelize is `5.3.0`.
The `migrations` table is correctly created to the `custom` schema, but migrations still run in `public` schema.

I get the following error when running migrations that do not specify the schema in the query itself. From the error we can see that the schema is undefined:

```
{ SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "oldtablename" does not exist
  at Query.formatError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:354:16)
  at query.catch.err (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:71:18)
  at tryCatcher (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
  at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
  at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
  at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
  at _drainQueueStep (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
  at _drainQueue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
  at Async._drainQueues (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
  at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
  at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
  at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
  at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
  at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:120:23)
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
parent:
 { error: relation "oldtablename" does not exist
     at Connection.parseE (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
     at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:379:19)
     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
     at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
   name: 'error',
   length: 118,
   severity: 'ERROR',
   code: '42P01',
   detail: undefined,
   hint: undefined,
   position: undefined,
   internalPosition: undefined,
   internalQuery: undefined,
   where: undefined,
   schema: undefined,
   table: undefined,
   column: undefined,
   dataType: undefined,
   constraint: undefined,
   file: 'namespace.c',
   line: '420',
   routine: 'RangeVarGetRelidExtended',
   sql:
    'ALTER TABLE "oldtablename" RENAME TO "newtablename";' },
original:
 { error: relation "oldtablename" does not exist
     at Connection.parseE (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
     at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:379:19)
     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
     at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
   name: 'error',
   length: 118,
   severity: 'ERROR',
   code: '42P01',
   detail: undefined,
   hint: undefined,
   position: undefined,
   internalPosition: undefined,
   internalQuery: undefined,
   where: undefined,
   schema: undefined,
   table: undefined,
   column: undefined,
   dataType: undefined,
   constraint: undefined,
   file: 'namespace.c',
   line: '420',
   routine: 'RangeVarGetRelidExtended',
   sql:
    'ALTER TABLE "oldtablename" RENAME TO "newtablename";' },
sql:
 'ALTER TABLE "oldtablename" RENAME TO "newtablename";' }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bit confusing but you need to define a searchpath and dialect option for the connection.

```
const sequelizeConn = new Sequelize(ENV_DB_URL, {
  schema: 'custom',
  logging: false,
  searchPath: 'custom',
  dialectOptions: {
    prependSearchPath: true
}
})
```

Comment: It seems that using `prependSearchPath: true` causes `Model.update` to fail with `Cannot insert multiple commands into prepared statement`. Here is the related issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10875

Comment: Is this still in production???

Comment: Works with sequelize version `6.21.3`